# "Connection Refused" running a server externally , although working locally

Tags: python, sockets

Trying to get into sockets and networking.
I wrote some simple server and client scripts and ran them,
which was working when connected locally and client-server communicated just fine, yet when my client script tries to connect to my_external_ip:open_port it gets a "Connection Refused" [WinError 10061]

I've opened a port (5234 in this case) and checked it using those port-scanning sites, what the server seems to react to and even accept connections.

Yet when I run my client script, it throws an exception, and the server doesn't seem to respond or even be aware of the connection attempt.

I've shut down my firewall temporarily and made sure I'm listening on 0.0.0.0:5234 (which to my understanding should be what I'm doing).

Am I missing something? doesn't make sense to me that the script runs locally, the server takes incoming external connections, yet this doesn't work.
Maybe the problem is that the client's outbound connection attempt is somehow blocked?

I cleaned up some unrelated code, but that's about it:

SERVER:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = ""  #Also tried socket.gethostname() and 0.0.0.0
port = 5234
s.bind((server,port))
s.listen()
connection, address = s.accept()
```

CLIENT:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server = my_public_ip
    self.port = 5234
    self.client.connect((self.server,self.port)
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but _In the Internet Protocol Version 4, the address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target._ (from Wiki) I'm not so familiar with ports and networking, but if you're testing locally, why aren't you using ```127.0.0.1:5234```?

Comment: well, I did test locally, which worked, I'm trying to figure out a way to test if it would work externally. I'm also running the client from the same network but trying to connect externally, I'm not sure about it but it just might be the problem.

Comment: @pavel listening on "0.0.0.0" is a way to say you want to listen on **all** interfaces. so on localhost, but also on your ethernet, wifi, vpn adresses

Comment: from the machine on which you try to run the client.

What happens if you type `telnet 81.218.131.123 5234`

Comment: @gelonida I get a connection failed, but when trying with 10.0.0.1:5234 it does work. and other incoming connections such as the check-port sites' also work. seems the router has a problem forwarding to itself or something, it only does this properly locally, but I wanted to try this on a public network for testing